# Probabilistic counting inequality

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory

I am reading a proof involving the existence of a property in a tournament (a directed complete graph).

To make the proof work, we need to have $n^ke^{-n/2^k}<1$. Here $n$ is the order of the tournament and $k$ is the order of some sub tournament.

The proof goes on to say that if $n>k^22^{k+1}$, then $n^ke^{-n/2^k}<1$, but I am not sure how to derive this bound on $n$? I have that
$$\begin{align*}
n^ke^{-n/2^k}&<1\\
e^{-n/2^k}&<n^{-k}\\
-\frac{n}{2^k}&<-k\ln{n}\\
\frac{n}{\ln{n}}&>k2^k
\end{align*}$$
Since $\ln{x}$ is an increasing function and $n\ge 2$ we have
$$
\frac{n}{\ln{2}}\ge\frac{n}{\ln{n}}>k2^k
$$
which yields
$$
n>k2^k\ln{2}.
$$
So I am guessing that since $2>\ln{2}$ and $k>1$, we have $n>k^22^{k+1}>k2^{k+1}>k2^k\ln{2}.$

Why not state the lower version of the bound, $k2^k\ln{2}$, instead of the seemingly contrived higher bound, $k^22^{k+1}$?

Comment: Does that relate to domination numbers (or, property $S_k$ as they call it) ?  It's resembling.  Anyway, maybe you could consider letting $n = (k^2 2^{k + 1})^j$ for some $j \geq 1$, then replace $n$ by this value in $n^ke^{-n/2^k}$.  You'll end up with something that does seem to be smaller than one (but showing it is something else...).

Comment: If $n>k^22^{k+1}$, then there is a tournament on $n$ players such that any subset $S$ of $k$ players has another player not in $S$ that beats all the players in $S$.

Comment: Yup, that's all about the domination number of tournaments.  There's a variant here on p161 if you're interested : http://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/29/ajc_v29_p157.pdf, though they don't explain where their bounds neither.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It looks like they prove a refinement of the bound Erdos proved in 1963, but not much more insight is available on the point I'm stuck on. :(

Comment: @LaarsHelenius I think I'm a bit confused. Above, didn't you show that $n^ke^{-n/2^k}<1 \Rightarrow n > k^2 2^{k+1}$? Also, is there a condition such as $k/2 > \log n$ in your problem?

Comment: I was trying to work backwards starting with $n^ke^{-n/2^k}<1$ to figure out how the bound on $n$ was derived. Also, the only restrictions on $n$ and $k$ are $n\ge 2$ and $n\ge k$.